# constructed tree of nodes, runs expectedly through debugger but doesn't show outcome on the console

Tags: java, algorithm, nodes

I have created a tree which uses recursion to add Nodes. The tree isn't a binary tree, but has the features of a binary tree:

- maximum of 2 child nodes

There is no ordering of elements, the Nodes are created going from left to right of the tree basically.

When the method has finished I return the root, however it only gives me the root, I do not know how to get it to show me all the nodes that have been constructed with their parent and child nodes when I call `preorderTravereTree`(Node focusNode) which I pass in the root node to the method.

I have debugged the addNode method and it constructs the tree successfully with the Nodes being assigned correctly to each parent, however I just don't see the outcome on the console.

the `addNode()` method:

```
 public Node addNode(int listIndex, Node root, Node focusNode, Node subLRoot, Node subRRoot, int key, String name, int managerId) {

    //if the length of all the lists which hold the same index and size is less than 8
    if (listIndex < 8) {

        // Create a new Node and initialize it
        Node newNode = new Node(key, name, managerId);
        // If there is no root this becomes root
        if (root == null) {
            root = newNode;
            return addNode(listIndex + 1, newNode, newNode, newNode, newNode, dt.getEmpIdLst()[listIndex + 1], dt.getEmpNameLst()[listIndex + 1], dt.getManagerIdLst()[listIndex + 1]);
        } else {

            Node parent;

           //the parent takes the focusNode which by default if the root

            parent = focusNode;

            //if what is on the left of the focusNode has no child node

            if (focusNode.leftChild == null) {

                //a node is constructed to the child of this parent.
                parent.leftChild = newNode;
                //the sub left branch of the tree is given to the subLRoot variable.
                subLRoot = parent.leftChild;
                //if the focusNode hasn't moved on from the root then we keep it as it is.
                if (focusNode.equals(root)) {
                    return addNode(listIndex + 1, root, root, subLRoot = parent.leftChild, subRRoot, dt.getEmpIdLst()[listIndex + 1], dt.getEmpNameLst()[listIndex + 1], dt.getManagerIdLst()[listIndex + 1]);
                } 
                //otherwise the focus node carries the value it currently holds meaning that the node is beyond the root.
                else {
                    return addNode(listIndex + 1, root, focusNode, subLRoot = parent.leftChild, subRRoot, dt.getEmpIdLst()[listIndex + 1], dt.getEmpNameLst()[listIndex + 1], dt.getManagerIdLst()[listIndex + 1]);
                }

                //if the right child of the parent is empty

            } else if (focusNode.rightChild == null) {

                //we check if the managerID's of both the current Node to be constructed and the left Node of the focusNode are the same.

                if ((newNode.managerId == focusNode.leftChild.managerId)) {

                  //if both ids match then we construct the current Node to the right side of the parent.
                    parent.rightChild = newNode;
                    //the sub right branch of the tree is given to the subRRoot variable.

                    subRRoot = parent.rightChild;

                    //if the focusNode hasn't moved on from the root then keep its value as the root
                    if (focusNode.equals(root)) {
                        return addNode(listIndex + 1, root, root, subLRoot, subRRoot = parent.rightChild, dt.getEmpIdLst()[listIndex + 1], dt.getEmpNameLst()[listIndex + 1], dt.getManagerIdLst()[listIndex + 1]);
                    } 
                    //otherwise if the listIndex+1 remains less than the size of each list (to avoid IndexOutOfBoundsException) we carry on and assign the SubLeftRoot of the tree to the focusNode going from left to right again

                    else if (listIndex + 1 != 8) {
                        return addNode(listIndex + 1, root, subLRoot, subLRoot = parent.leftChild, subRRoot, dt.getEmpIdLst()[listIndex + 1], dt.getEmpNameLst()[listIndex + 1], dt.getManagerIdLst()[listIndex + 1]);
                    } else {

                        //this is finally where the method ends However I cannot seem to see the whole tree constructed although through debugging all the nodes
                        //assign as they should!

                        return root;

                    }
                    //otherwise the managerID's of both current Node to be constructed and left Node aren't the same.
                } else {
                   //the parent becomes the right branch of the tree.

                    parent = subRRoot;
                    //if the left child of the parent is null.

                    if (parent.leftChild == null) {
                        //construct the new Node on the left side of the parent.

                        parent.leftChild = newNode;

                        //pass on the parent to the focusNode which will end up in the right branch of the tree.
                        return addNode(listIndex + 1, root, parent, subLRoot, subRRoot, dt.getEmpIdLst()[listIndex + 1], dt.getEmpNameLst()[listIndex + 1], dt.getManagerIdLst()[listIndex + 1]);
                    } else {
                        //otherwise put the Node in the rightChild of the node.

                        parent.rightChild = newNode;
                        return addNode(listIndex + 1, root, subLRoot, subLRoot, subRRoot, dt.getEmpIdLst()[listIndex + 1], dt.getEmpNameLst()[listIndex + 1], dt.getManagerIdLst()[listIndex + 1]);
                    }
                }
                //Otherwise...

            } else {
                //focusNode becomes the left childNode of the tree.

                focusNode = subLRoot;

                //if the listIndex < 8

                if (listIndex < 8) {

              //iwe return the method again and the focusNode becomes the left child node of itself.
                    return addNode(listIndex, root, subLRoot, subLRoot, subRRoot, dt.getEmpIdLst()[listIndex], dt.getEmpNameLst()[listIndex], dt.getManagerIdLst()[listIndex]);
                }

            }

        }

    }
    return root;

}
```

The `preorderTraverseTree()` method:

```
public void preorderTraverseTree(Node focusNode) {

    if (focusNode != null) {

        System.out.print(focusNode);
        preorderTraverseTree(focusNode.leftChild);
        preorderTraverseTree(focusNode.rightChild);
    }
}
```

The Main Method and Constructor:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {



    BinaryTree_1 theTree = new BinaryTree_1();



}



public BinaryTree_1() {

     dt = new DataExtractor();

     dt.openFile();
     dt.readEmpIdAndNme();
     dt.readManagerId();
     dt.closeFile();
    System.out.println(addNode(lindex,root, focusNode,subLeftRoot,subRightRoot, dt.getEmpIdLst()[0], dt.getEmpNameLst()[lindex], dt.getManagerIdLst()[lindex]));
    preorderTraverseTree(root);

}
```

The `preorderTraverse()` method prints nothing to the console and `addNode()` returns me the root node 'Dangermouse (1)->'.

The data below are the arrays of data I am working with so first node has `1,Dangermouse,0` so on and so forth.

The console:

```
`[1, 2, 3, 6, 12, 15, 16, 17]
```

[Dangermouse, Gonzo the Great, Invisible Woman, Black Widow, Hit Girl, Super Ted, Batman,             Catwoman]
   [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 6, 6]
   Dangermouse (1) -> 
   BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)`

Comment: Can you also show what your Node class looks like?

Answer (score 0):

The most likely problem here is that `print()` prints a string, and a focusNode is not a string. Use the `focusNode.toString();` method.

```
public void preorderTraverseTree(Node focusNode) {

    if (focusNode != null) {

        System.out.print(focusNode.toString());
        preorderTraverseTree(focusNode.leftChild);
        preorderTraverseTree(focusNode.rightChild);
    }
}
```